# ArcGIS: Auto-Calculate Field Value from Other Fields

Tags: python, attributes, arcgis, arcmap

I searched for a question similar to mine, but couldn't find something precisely similar, so if this has been answered already, I apologize.

I am creating a ROW shapefile that contains (among others) 3 fields: 
"Liber"
"Page"
"ROWID"

Currently I have "Liber" and "Page" set as text values (though that may later change to a numerical data type), and "ROWID" as a text value. Is it possible to write a script that will automatically calculate "ROWID" as:

"ROW-" + !Liber! + !Page!

I'm trying to set this up for someone to enter data without needing to do much more than enter values in the "Liber" and "Page" fields. If it isn't possible to do it this way, how can I set it so that someone can right-click the "ROWID" field, select "Calculate Values" (which I actually can't find anymore; did they remove this from outside the Geoprocessing Toolbox?), and have it run the above Python script? I can't really expect the data entry person to run the field calculator every time they need to calculate a new "ROWID" value, unfortunately.

Please let me know if this isn't making sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this that I can think of is to use Calculate Field. In this case, the script would be:

`FC = path to shapefile`

`field = "ROWID"`

`arcpy.CalculateField(FC, field, '!Liber! + !Page!', "PYTHON_9.3")`